# Spring Data: several implementations

Tags: java, spring-data

In usual Spring MVC I can create a Dao interface along with several implementations of this interface for different Spring profiles. But if I want to implement Spring Data, there is a problem: how to create those implementations? The idea of adding a custom repository, described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation), never solves this problem...

Example.
Dao:

```
public interface DaoExample extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, DaoExampleCustom {
}
```

DaoCustom:

```
public interface DaoExampleCustom {

    void someMethod(User user);
}
```

DaoExampleImpl:

```
@Profile("someProfile")
public class DaoExampleImpl implements DaoExampleCustom {
    @Override
    public void someMethod(User user) {

    }
}
```

While DaoExample and DaoExampleImpl belong to different profiles, this code will fail to start. Moreover, what if I want to create several DaoExampleImpl for different profiles? I should name them like DaoExampleImpl1, DaoExampleImp2, etc. But this violates Spring Data's naming convention. Does it mean that if I need to create a dao layer for several Spring profiles, I should avoid using Spring Data at all?

Comment: I don't fully understand the requirements. Can't you just add `public interface DaoExample extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, DaoExampleCustom`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this into the code example. I have corrected the text.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you properly you need multiple `DaoExampleImpl` classes

```
@Profile("someProfile")
public class DaoExampleImpl implements DaoExampleCustom

@Profile("someProfile2")
public class DaoExampleImpl implements DaoExampleCustom
```

Can't you just place them in a separate packages and adapt package scan to include necessary package according to desired profile. Thus Spring data naming convention is safe and you can use different implementations. Just an idea.

Comment: That might work, but... In the end it looks more difficult than the creation of dao layer without Spring Data at all. So, I think the whole idea of using Spring Data makes sense just in case of the only "implementation". Otherwise it should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

There are probably hacks to make it work. The one proposed by @StanslavL should work.

An alternative would be to register the implementation as a Bean, I think that should take precedence over classes found by Spring Data, which it would have to register itself.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-764 describes a similar problem and a workaround using different `repositoryImplementationPostfix' which you could put on different Profiles.

But all these approaches don't really appeal to me. Instead, I would provide a single implementation class, which then delegates the actual work to a different bean, which you can switch using profiles. This way you don't depend on the special ways Spring Data does its thing.